# Find corresponding row or get next row in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
id value1 value2
1  1      6
2  8      10
3  14     20
```

Then I have a number, let's say `x=7`.

**My query should find out id for which x falls between value1 and value2. If x does not fall in any range, use next id.** In my case `x=7` I'd get `id=2`.

My guess it could be done somehow using windowing functions in PostgreSQL, but maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: but what is x, there is no such field in the table.

Comment: It could be something in WHERE condition. SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=7 AND x BETWEEN value1 AND value2; etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from t
where 7 <= v2
order by v1
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you actually want a list of possible results (if `x` matches more than one line, you want them all; else just the last one). In light of this, I thought of the following solution:

```
SELECT    CASE
        WHEN 
            (
            SELECT    COUNT(*)
            FROM      table
            WHERE       x > value1
                    AND x < value2
            ) > 0
        THEN 
            (
            SELECT    id
            FROM      table
            WHERE       x > value1
                    AND x < value2
            )
        ELSE
            (
            SELECT    MAX(id)
            FROM      table
            )
        END AS my_ids
```